# Flask-sqlalchemy use only one connection to mysql

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have Flask application with Flask-sqlalchemy extension.

All my requests are going through one connection to mySQL. So, if one of user get page with long query — all outhers are waiting for end of this query.

I've played with POOL settings from help page (http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html), but got nothing.

What should i do?

Comment: have checked there really is only one connection (by default, there should be 5)? Are you sure you simply aren't overworking your DB server?

Comment: I'm checking by "show processlist;" in mysql — and there is only one row (second is for client where i execute "show processlist").

Comment: I'm sure that there is no overworking processes. May be smth is in MySQLdb module? Or witch one use sqlalchemy for connect?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the flask devserver which is single-process/thread and thus only one connection at a time?

Comment: No. I use mod_wsgi and apache2 — with help page http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/mod_wsgi/.